# How to remove an array object with reference to the object

Tags: javascript

I have an object and one array which having most of the identical data. But few of the data in array is more than in object. I want to remove those perticular data from array which is not in object.

Here is my object

```
Obj = {
    "USA" :{
        "Country" : "USA",
        "Capital" : "WDC",
        "Rank" : "1",
        "UID" : "USA"
    },
    "UK" :{
        "Country" : "UK",
        "Capital" : "LONDON",
        "Rank" : "2",
        "UID" : "UK"
    }
}
```

Here is my array.

```
myArray = [ {
                "Country" : "USA",
                "Capital" : "WDC",
                "Rank" : "1",
                "UID" : "USA"
            },{
                "Country" : "UK",
                "Capital" : "LONDON",
                "Rank" : "2",
                "UID" : "UK"
            },{
                "Country" : "China",
                "Capital" : "Beijing",
                "Rank" : "3",
                "UID" : "China"
            }]
```

You can `myArray[2]` is extra in myArraywhich is not in object. How to remove  this.

My code which I am trying is :

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.UID !== 'China';
    });
```

But this is not a dynamic. I mean `UID` could be anything.

Comment: `return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Obj, obj.UID);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming that `Obj`'s keys are not always exactly same as its value's `UID`**, try below solution.

You need to first iterate your `Obj`'s keys and make an array of all the **allowed `UID`'s**

```
var allowedUIDs = Object.values(Obj).map( s => sObj[s].UID );
```

IE compatible version

```
var allowedUIDs = Object.keys(Obj).map( function( s ){ return Obj[s].UID });
```

Now filter out `myarray` by those values which are not in `allowedUIDs`

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
    return allowedUIDs.indexOf( obj.UID ) != -1;  //only those which are in allowedIDs are kept
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var Obj = {
    "USA" :{
        "Country" : "USA",
        "Capital" : "WDC",
        "Rank" : "1",
        "UID" : "USA"
    },
    "UK" :{
        "Country" : "UK",
        "Capital" : "LONDON",
        "Rank" : "2",
        "UID" : "UK"
    }
};

var myArray = [ {
    "Country" : "USA",
    "Capital" : "WDC",
    "Rank" : "1",
    "UID" : "USA"
},{
    "Country" : "UK",
    "Capital" : "LONDON",
    "Rank" : "2",
    "UID" : "UK"
},{
    "Country" : "China",
    "Capital" : "Beijing",
    "Rank" : "3",
    "UID" : "China"
}];

var allowedUIDs = Object.values(Obj).map( s => s.UID );

console.log( allowedUIDs )

var output = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
    return allowedUIDs.indexOf( obj.UID ) != -1; 
}); 

console.log( output );
```

Comment: You've turned a simple O(n) algorithm into a more complicated O(n*m) algorithm.

Comment: @melpomene How?

Comment: @melpomene Did you made an assumption that key name will always be equal to `UID` value, when OP never mentioned the same?

Comment: Yes, I did. Technically OP also never said that he wants to compare the `UID` keys (only).

Comment: Nope, he said *I want to remove those perticular data from array which is not in object* and `UID` is part of the same object. Did you down-voted everyone without validating your assumption with OP?

Comment: Part of the object, but if you take OP's description literally, you'd have to compare the whole object (with all keys). Even then I don't see a reason to use an array instead of a lookup table.

Comment: @melpomene *you'd have to compare the whole object* **Object with a UID!**   *Even then I don't see a reason to use an array instead of a lookup table.* You don't see a reason? Yes, it would have been a bad answer if there million items in the array and map would have made a significant difference. Otherwise, I don't see how using an array made this a wrong answer! So, basically you down-voted because your preferred method wasn't used?

Comment: "Object with a UID" and Country and Capital and Rank. Your code doesn't handle those. Also, how do you know there aren't a million items in the array?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Why should he? It's obvious that the OP is dealing with countries. So the `keys` should be equal to the `UID`. If they are not, that's the OP's problem. He should reorganize his data to get the most performance/productivity. Also if you're referring to _"I mean UID could be anything."_, I think what he means by that is that `UID` could be any **country**.

Comment: @melpomene Still with an **ID** which represents the object! If there are million items in the array you think loading all of them in memory and keep a map is a better solution? **Now you are simply nitpicking!!** How do I know there is no list of million countries, I wonder!

Comment: @akinuri *So the keys should be equal to the UID. If they are not, that's the OP's problem.* Really? Why would it be OP's problem if you have made your assumptions?

Comment: There is no **ID**, just a property called `UID`. Why are you assuming those uniquely identify an object, but the keys of the container object don't when they are actually guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @melpomene *Why are you assuming those uniquely identify an object* Maybe because OP specifically asked for a comparison with `UID` instead of comparison with key name only!

Comment: Where did OP specifically ask for that?

Comment: @melpomene `return obj.UID !== 'China';` Why is OP comparing the UID for *I want to remove those perticular data from array which is not in object.* ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Not assumption, but pattern recognition. Keys correspond to the `UID` property of the values. So I think it's safe to say they are equal to each other. If not, again, OP should handle it. Saying otherwise would be nitpicking. Then OP should have mentioned how he created the `Obj` and `myArray` in the first place... Anyway. Don't reply to me. I'll leave you guys to it.

Comment: @gurvinder372 But this won't work in IE. `=>` throwing an error

Comment: @gurvinder372 One thing I notice for IE `Object.values` throwing an error. I am trying with `Object.keys` but again no luck. It is throwing error in chrome

Comment: @David Try now with Object.keys

Answer (score 1):

Almost there... Use below

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.UID in Obj ;
});
```

Comment: That would be better written as `return obj.UID in Obj;`.

Comment: Wouldn't in operator loop through with O(n) time complexity where as direct map look up is O(1) time complexity?

Comment: No, why would `in` loop?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. You can use in operator to find an element in an array as well. In that case, the implementation has to loop through the array right? I wonder how the implementation of in operator for map objects.

Comment: No, you can't use `in` for array elements. You can use it for array indices, though: `1 in ["a", "b", "c"]` is `true`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your object keys to be UIDs, you can filter by checking if those keys exist in the Object like

```js
Obj = {
    "USA" :{
        "Country" : "USA",
        "Capital" : "WDC",
        "Rank" : "1",
        "UID" : "USA"
    },
    "UK" :{
        "Country" : "UK",
        "Capital" : "LONDON",
        "Rank" : "2",
        "UID" : "UK"
    }
}

myArray = [ {
                "Country" : "USA",
                "Capital" : "WDC",
                "Rank" : "1",
                "UID" : "USA"
            },{
                "Country" : "UK",
                "Capital" : "LONDON",
                "Rank" : "2",
                "UID" : "UK"
            },{
                "Country" : "China",
                "Capital" : "Beijing",
                "Rank" : "3",
                "UID" : "China"
            }]

myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
        return Obj[obj.UID] !== 'undefined';
    });
    
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: You've turned a simple O(n) algorithm into a more complicated O(n*m) algorithm.

Comment: @melpomene, you are right, I just realised that, updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use check if the `UID` is in the keys of the obj using `in` operator.

```js
const obj = {
  "USA": {
    "Country": "USA",
    "Capital": "WDC",
    "Rank": "1",
    "UID": "USA"
  },
  "UK": {
    "Country": "UK",
    "Capital": "LONDON",
    "Rank": "2",
    "UID": "UK"
  }
}


const myArray = [{
  "Country": "USA",
  "Capital": "WDC",
  "Rank": "1",
  "UID": "USA"
}, {
  "Country": "UK",
  "Capital": "LONDON",
  "Rank": "2",
  "UID": "UK"
}, {
  "Country": "China",
  "Capital": "Beijing",
  "Rank": "3",
  "UID": "China"
}]

const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
const result = myArray.filter((item) => item.UID in obj)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You've turned a simple O(n) algorithm into a more complicated O(n*m) algorithm.

Comment: @felixmosh  This is not compatible to IE,